# ACF Taxonomy search on backend (Relationship field)

Tags: plugins, filters, advanced-custom-fields, request-filter

I'm working on a project where I have to filter every Products:product_cat type of taxonomies on ACF. I need those product post type values which contains these taxonomy on the search field. Sadly ACF only supports acf/get_taxonomies_for_select and not like acf/get_post_types. I started with this code, so now I can show all the Taxonomies, but I can't made any filter to it:

```
// vars
$simple_value = false;
$choices = apply_filters('acf/get_taxonomies_for_select', $choices, $simple_value);


// create field
do_action('acf/create_field', array(
'type'  =>  'select',
'name'  =>  '',
'class' =>  'select-post_type',
'value' =>  '',
'choices' => $choices,
));
```

Comment: Someone made a post type select field for ACF. https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-select-for-advanced-custom-fields/ Mabye its useful. Otherwise you could create the choices yourself with the get_post_types function instead of using a filter

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sadly I don't know how to filter it by product_cat taxonomies before array merge